# Send JSON object from webpage to Android app

Tags: javascript, android

I'm browsing the web to find out this, but I'm not lucky (or unskilled) in finding anything similar. The project is just in the "Idea" step at the moment, and the part I'm having trouble finding a way to do is sending a JSON object from a webpage to an Android application where it would be handled. The process would be as follows:

1. User fills data on webpage and submits it
2. Data is formatted as JSON
3. JSON is pushed to the Android application - need help
4. Android application processes the JSON object

I presume there are specifics that need to be set on both sides (Webpage and Android) in order for it to work. Perhaps there's an easier (correct) way to do it, maybe even different approach in general.

Any help and advice is much appreciated.

EDIT: If it is possible I would like to avoid outside services, and would rather prefer a direct communication between the webpage and android application if it is possible.

I forgot to mention I control both the webpage and the android application

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar when building a OAuth2 Module for my company. So my answer in principle may relate to OAuth2 but the same concept applies.

Register an activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` This will be the activity that will be responsible for doing something with the return information.

Example

```
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".BaseOAuth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="oauth"
                android:scheme="example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the `onResume()` you can use the method `getIntent().getData()` for which you can run querys' on.

Example

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         Uri data = getIntent().getData();
         String code = data.getQueryParameter("code") == null ? "" :data.getQueryParameter("code");
    }
```

In the above instance, I do provide a callback URL where the website redirects me too. `example://oauth` Where in the OnResume I get the information returned.

Comment: I see, but how would the webpage send the JSON to the aplication? Bare in mind the user is wisiting the webpage from outside the Android App, not inside.

Comment: Thats up to the webpage owner. In Oauth you provide a redirect URL that's registered to the app. If the website doesn't redirect to where you specify then will be harder to get the JSON back.

Comment: I understand. Since im the owner of the webpage I must do the part there to :D Maybe I should add that to the question, so it's clear that I will control both the webpage and the android application.

Comment: You would need to do a redirect which can vary in webserver dependant if you are using a framework etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use firebase cloud messaging from google [firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or other service that send push message